# Is there any difference in the use of the signals post_delete and post_save?

Tags: django

I am trying to implement a couple of signals for creating and removing and deleting some files that are generated when an instance is created or removed from the database.

Right now the following code is working:

```
class Document(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        create = self.pk is None
        super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if create:
            os.makedirs(self.get_root_path())
            self.process_file()

from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Document)
def document_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    shutil.rmtree(instance.get_root_path(), ignore_errors=True)
    instance.docfile.delete(False)
```

The post_delete signal is working. When I try to set the post_save signal (instead of over writing the save method), it doesn't work. The signal is never called.

```
class Document(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):

    ...


from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Document)
def document_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    shutil.rmtree(instance.get_root_path(), ignore_errors=True)
    instance.docfile.delete(False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Document)
def document_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "this is never called"
    if created:
        os.makedirs(instance.get_root_path())
        instance.process_file()
```

Is there any difference between the way I have to configure a post_delete and a post_save?

Is it possible that the multiple inheritance is affecting this in a strange way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the model you are inheriting have a post_save method defined aswell.

From Django documentation:

> In some circumstances, the module in which you are connecting signals may be imported multiple times. This can cause your receiver function to be registered more than once, and thus called multiples times for a single signal event.

The solution is to set a unique identifier to your signal like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
import uuid

"""Class Document"""

def document_save(sender,instance,*args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        os.makedirs(instance.get_root_path())
        instance.process_file()

post_save.connect(document_save, dispatch_uid=str(uuid.uuid1()),sender = Document)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but I still have a problem with it. It is called in any related save. When I try to use the sender parameter in the connect, it doesn't work `post_save.connect(gen_key, sender=Document`, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")`.